# share statement can't be declared within a function definition in DolphinDB

Tags: database, stream-processing, dolphindb

I'm trying the [stream processing](https://github.com/dolphindb/Tutorials_EN/blob/master/streaming_tutorial.md) feature of dolphindb. And I want another node to subscribe to the current node, so I wrote some code like following. But the dolphindb GUI somehow report `Syntax Error: [line #2] share statement can't be declared within a function definition.` Does that mean, I have to open another session, then connect to `NODE2` and subscribe manually?

```
def mySub(PUBNODE, src) {
    share streamTable(1:0, [`c1], [INT]) as t
    subscribeTable(server=PUBNODE, tableName = src, handler = objByName(`t))
}

share streamTable(1:0, [`c1], [INT]) as `src
rpc(NODE2, mySub, getNodeAlias(), `src)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use share function to share a streaming table across sessions.

```
def mySub(PUBNODE, src) {
    share(streamTable(1:0, [`c1], [INT]), "t")
    subscribeTable(server=PUBNODE, tableName = src, handler = objByName(`t))
}
```